# setArgument not working in passing data in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to pass data between two fragment,

Here is my setArgument

```
ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("Test", "test");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And here is my `getArgument`

In my `onCreate` method

```
String test = args.getString("Test","test");

if(this.getArguments()!=null)
{
    Log.d("hey", "hey");
    test = this.getArguments().getString("Test","test");
    details_id.setText(test);
}
```

I have `java.lang.NullPointerException` for `details_id.setText(test);`

My get Argument is working I can get hey: hey in my log but my `setArgument` is not working.

> UPDATE

I don't have any error now but I cannot pass any argument

Here is my updated `onCreate` method

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    chooseTrip(tripIds.get(position));

    String selectedTripId = tripIds.get(position);

    Helpers.saveToSharedPreferences(getActivity(),
            Constants_Prefs.SELECTED_TOP_LEVEL_RECORD,
            Constants_Keys.SELECTED_TRIP_ID,
            selectedTripId);

    ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("Test", "test");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View fragV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)fragV.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    TextView details_id = (TextView)fragV.findViewById(R.id.detail_header_id);
    details_id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(this.getArguments()!=null){
        Log.d("hey", "hey");
        test = this.getArguments().getString("Test","t");
        details_id.setText(test);
    }
}
```

My Log: hey﹕ hey

My `textView` print:
if I use `test = this.getArguments().getString("Test","t");` -> my `textView` is t

If I use `test = this.getArguments().getString("Test");` -> my `textView` is nothing

Comment: Could you please elaborate "not working"? test is not set? Do you get an exception? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the `setArguments()` is not working?

Comment: @fasteque I added update I got  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @SamRad since I have java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Probably `details_id` is null and not the `test`. If you post your full code we can help more.

Comment: Please past the logcat, but since onCreate is called before onCreateView, I guess details_id is null. Try to retrieve the arguments in the onCreateView after having got details_id from the view.

Comment: @SamRad so how can I add this test print to my textView my textview is on onCreateView

Comment: Get the arguments in the onCreateView after you get your textview. Or save the string passed in the arguments in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Its not your `getArguments()` that is not working. You are calling `details_id.setText(test)` in `onCreate(Bundle  savedInstanceState)`. I am assuming that `details_id` is a `TextView`?

You have to initialize the views of a fragment in its `onCreateView` method, which is called after `onCreate` by the system

==========EDIT=======

Try this in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View fragV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)fragV.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    TextView details_id = (TextView)fragV.findViewById(R.id.detail_header_id);
    details_id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(this.getArguments()!=null){
        Log.d("hey", "hey");
        test = this.getArguments().getString("Test","t");
        details_id.setText(test);
    }
    return fragV;
}
```

Try this in your activity that creates the fragments:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("Test", "test");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    showFragment(fragment, true);
}

private void showFragment(Fragment frag, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();


    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

And your main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its just the name I chose for the View, as in its the top level fragment view, ie fragV

Comment: what error are you getting now? can you post the complete onCreate and onViewCreated methods you have?

Comment: Did it solved the problem? if yes then can you mark as answer?

Comment: why add to backstack?